# convert youtube audio to wav for linux without ffmpeg or avconv

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, unix, conversion, audio-conversion

Is there a simple command-line utility for unix available to use to convert an .m4a audio file or .webm file (that I can generate from youtube-dl) to a wave (.wav) file?

I tried ffmpeg and it gives me errors when I tried converting to any output format and it also creates zero-byte files.

I also don't have avconv but when I looked at its documentation online I think it wants to install the same libraries ffmpeg already installed.

But rather than installing an elaborate package (as I am low on disk space), isn't there a simple utility that can do this task for unix?

Comment: I'd question the premise: `youtube-dl` uses `ffmpeg` in some cases to convert the dashboard audio, and it works fine. So the real question is why your `ffmpeg` doesn't work, and that can have a number of reasons, from "outdated version" to "give it the right options".

Comment: Agreed. Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from here:

http://lifeofageekadmin.com/convert-m4a-mp3-linux/

I just have to execute:

```
faad -o outputfile.wav inputfile.m4a
```